# Why when looping in timer tick event over images list it's throwing exception parameter is not valid?

Tags: c#, winforms

System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myGifList[i]);
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                bmp.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

After the loop end it's throwing the exception.

Before that I did :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(myGifList[i]);
            }
        }
```

But then it's throwing out of memory exception.

And before all that the first time I tried this :

```
int counter = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(counter == 10)
            {
                counter = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myGifList[counter]);
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            }

            counter++;
        }
```

This is working the images are looping in the pictureBox1 but after some time it's throwing the out of memory exception.

The full code :

I'm downloading images then reading the images back to a List then trying to display them in a picutreBox1 and using trackBar1 to change the looping speed of the images in the pictureBox1 with a timer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> myGifList = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {            
            List<string> times = new List<string>();
            string t = "";

            InitializeComponent();

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
            {
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36");
                client.DownloadFile("https://myimages/", @"D:\localfile.html");

                var file = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\localfile.html");

                int idx = file.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push");
                int idx1 = file.IndexOf("</script>", idx);

                string results = file.Substring(idx, idx1 - idx);

                var statements = results.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < statements.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 10)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    string number = statements[i].Split('\'')[1];

                    times.Add(number); // add to a list instead

                    var link = "https://myimages" + number;
                    client.DownloadFile(link, @"D:\Images\Image" + i + ".jpeg");
                }
            }

            FileInfo[] fi;
            DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Images");
            fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.jpeg");
            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
            {
                myGifList.Add(fi[i].FullName);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        int counter = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(counter == 10)
            {
                counter = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myGifList[counter]);
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            }

            counter++;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 100 * trackBar1.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why are you running loop and setting the same control ?

Comment: This loop will finish within milliseconds. There's no way you're going to be able to see the images other than the very last one. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Sidenote: You don't need to initialize a new bitmap every time you want to display it in your picture box.

Comment: If you're trying to iterate through the images on a specific interval, get rid of the `for` loop in your last solution and keep the `counter` variable. But instead of checking if `counter == 10`, check if `counter == GifList.Count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem like you're trying to loop over `myGifList`, but then you've hardcoded a value of `10` in the method.

However, the bigger issue is that you're not even using `i` defined by the loop, so you're just overriding the same `Bitmap` `myGifList.Count` times, for nothing - making your code inefficient.

Try:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (counter == myGifList.Count)
      counter = 0;

   pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();

   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myGifList[counter]);
   pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

   counter++;
}
```

**Note that you should use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?` to prevent a possible `NullReferenceException` when calling `.Dispose()`:**

`pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();`

This would happen on the first time setting the image as `pictureBox1.Image` would be `null`, causing `.Dispose()` to throw an exception.

---

Even better would be to use the [`PictureBox.ImageLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) property which would allow you to display the image without creating a `Bitmap` object every time:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (counter == myGifList?.Count)
      counter = 0;

   pictureBox1.ImageLocation = myGifList[counter];

   counter++;
}
```

---

Sidenote: the `Timer.Interval` property is also in [milliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.interval?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), so I'd bump up the `100` value you have in `trackBar1_Scroll(...)` if you want to actually be able to see the images looping.

Comment: Good thing suggesting the `ImageLocation` property. In the Bitmap example, just remember to dispose of the previous bmp before creating a new one: `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();`

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes definitely, updated answer - thanks!